# Tosca : how to use make a web element wait for another one to be selected first

Tags: web, automation, element, wait, tosca

I'm automating a page with Tosca , and i want my first web element to hold until the second one is selected, so then the first one will be selected last .
Is it possible ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you should be able to do what you are wanting by [reordering the attributes](https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1520/en/content/tosca_commander/teststeps_xteststeps.htm#OptionsforTestSteps) within the test step so that your first element is below the second.

You can allow the attributes to be re-ordered by single-right-clicking on the test step and selecting "Allow reorder". Then re-order by dragging and dropping the element to the desired spot.